# How can i add a face recognition in my rails in ruby on rails 5?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, face-recognition, image-recognition

I have one app where i have a scaffold with a register of peoples with photo, but for me search if the people have your datas registered in my system i need use face recognition for read face in web camera and read the photos of database and if search the people return your personal datas, how i can make this in rails ?

I need to implement this as soon as possible in my system, but I couldn't find anything on the internet very specific.

Answer (score 1):

This question is far too broad to answer in any detail, but face recognition integration currently involves:

1. Selecting a backend recognition provider like [Microsoft Face](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/face/), [Amazon ReKognition](https://aws.amazon.com/rekognition/), [Google Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/) or any number of other cloud solutions that meet whatever your needs and budget require.
2. Selecting and implementing a Javascript library for capturing images.
3. Using the provider's SDK or REST API to integrate recognition into your application.

Googling for 'ruby face recognition' immediately returned tutorials and documentation for integrating with the Amazon, Microsoft, and Google solutions plus a few others, so there are lots of resources available once you have selected the provider.